# Call webservice from SQL stored procedure and want to know ResponseText Charset

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding

I want to call a webservice from my stored procedure and get an XML answer. I can get XML answer OK but I want to change responsetext charset utf-8 or euc-kr. How to change the responsetext charset?

Ps. I Used [sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream'] but couldn't get responsebody
so I want to  charset responsetext utf-8 or euc-kr

This is what my stored procedure looks like:

```
        DECLARE @Object       INT 
                  , @hResult       INT
                  , @source        NVARCHAR(255)
                  , @desc           NVARCHAR(255)
                  , @Method     NVARCHAR(MAX) 
                  , @ResponseText     VARCHAR(MAX) 
                  , @ResponseBody     varbinary(MAX) 
            DECLARE @ObjectToken INT

             -- OLE 호출 --XML
            EXEC @hResult = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;

            EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'GET',@URL,0--'false'                                                                                                  
            Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'Content-Type' ,'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
            EXEC @hResult = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'

            EXEC sp_OAGetProperty  @Object, 'ResponseText'--,@ResponseBody OUT


            EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object 
            --SELECT @ResponseBody AS ResponseBody



            RETURN 
             -- OLE -ADODB
            EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
            EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
            EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Position ', 0                
            EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
            EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL,@ResponseBody
            EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Position ', 0                
            EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 2               
            EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Charset ', 'euc-kr'    

            EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'ReadText'

            EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'


           --EXEC @hResult =   sp_OAMethod @Object, 'ResponseText'--, @ResponseText OUTPUT


        --   INSERT INTO TempReceiveXml_Body 
        --   exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responsebody'

            EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object 
            EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Must response webpage  encoding type = utf-8 then OK. simple.....solution
Dont need this sentence...

```
  Exec sp_OAMethod @Object ,'setRequestHeader'    ,NULL ,'Content-Type' ,'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
```